# Conteudo de um campo do form como parametro de pesqusia

Tags: javascript, firebase, firestore

Eu tenho um form com os seguintes campos (vou colocar apenas um, como exemplo):

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="nomeAutor"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account material-icons-name"></i></label>
<input type="text" name="nomeAutor" id="nomeAutor" placeholder="Nome do autor" />
</div>
```

Eu tb setei o `querySelector()` para registrar o valor do campo:

```
var nomeDoAutor = document.querySelector("#nomeAutor").value;
```

E finalmente, escrevi o código para fazer a pesquisa e renderizar a lista de resultados:

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", event => {
     db.collection("textos").where('nomeDoAutor', '==', 'nomeAutorTexto').get().then((snapshot) => {
         snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
         console.log(doc.data())
         renderLista(doc)
         });
     });
 });
```

Mas ... não funcionou :-(

No que estou errando?

Grato!

Comment: Você está comparando a string literal 'nomeDoAutor' com 'nomeAutorTexto'? Não era para estar comparando a varável `nomeDoAutor` com 'nomeAutorTexto'? Além disso lembre-se de pegar o valor do elemento '#nomeAutor' depois do click, não antes.

Comment: "_Não funcionou_" pode ser muitas coisas. O que não funcionou? Qual foi o resultado? Mostra erro no console ou mostra em branco?

Comment: @user140828, bem pontuado, acho que entendi, vou tentar :-)

Comment: @Sam, o console fica em branco. Vou testar a sugestão do colega acima e volto em instantes!

Comment: @user140828, deixei a captura do valor para a `var nomeDoAutor` depois do click, mas ainda não funcionou e como eu disse pro @Sam, o console fica em branco.

Eu tb ACHEI que havia entendido sua colocação sobre comparação das variaveis mas de verdade não entendi, pois ainda ACHO que logica esta correta.

Poderia aprofundar sua sugestão, lembrando sempre da minha noobice ?

Comment: @Sam, `'nomeAutorTexto'` é o campo do BD com o qual preciso pesquio pesuisar o valor do campo `nomeDoAutor`.

Segui sua sugestão e o console deu uma memsagem de erro:

_Error: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Invalid field path (). Paths must not be empty, begin with '.', end with '.', or contain '..'_

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Uma coisa estranha: apesar de mandar no console `firebase init` e `firebase deploy`, na seção Functions do console do Firebase não tem nenhuma função listada.

Perdidaço agora :-(